# How to set the axis tick to be only major on python

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

[image]I am using a contour plot to generate a table of values (I'm interested in the deviance between cases and not the actual value). The Z axis is a regular 2d array of values. The X and Y axis however are 2d vectors which I convert to a number using this formula:

```
v = (x,y)
val = x*5 + y + 2
```

where `0<=x<=2` and `-2<=y<=2`.

I want the axis to include all the vector pairs so I created an array (`xlabels`) which looks like:

```
xlabel=[[0,-2], [0,-1], ..., [0,2], ... , [2,1], 2,2]]
```

When I try to apply this to my plot, I get only the first set of values which are set the major ticks label. The line I use is:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
```

and the result I get (the top xaxis):

How can I set the xaxis labels to all appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a locator:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
locator = MultipleLocator(1)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax1.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
```